# New browsers windows are always full screen

Tags: gnome, firefox, window, window-manager, maximized

I have the feeling I am missing something obvious, but if I knew I wouldn't be asking ... every time I create a new browser window in Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04, the window size of the new window fills the entire screen. On a 4K monitor, that's a bit excessive for a web browser window. How do I set the default size of new browser windows to be something smaller?

Comment: Firefox remembers the state of the last closed window between restarts. So make sure the last window you close has the size you are after. What also may be a factor: for near-maximized windows, the window manager is set by default to auto-maximize them.

Comment: @vanadium honestly, that is the behavior I'd expect, but it is not the behavior I am getting. The last window size is not used when creating a new window.

Comment: Is your last window size significantly smaller than your screen, e.g. half tiled, or just a small window? Just to exclude the effect where quite large windows by default are full screened automatically.

Comment: @vanadium I usually resize the window to about 1/3 of the monitor width and maybe 90% of the monitor's height.

Comment: @pomsky Thanks! That has fixed my problem